# How to format the output of the javascript function date() ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to format javascript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date)

I have the following bit of code

```
 $('#ins_date').attr('value', Date());
```

What i get is this : Wed Mar 21 2012 17:52:32 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)

How could i format this string to get somethingh like this : 2012-03-01

Answer (score 1):

[date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is the best I've found.  It supports many different formats.

Answer (score -1):

Best option for now is using [moment.js](http://www.momentjs.com) library. Formatting for native Javascript Date is not well supported.

```
var now = moment();
now.format("YY-MM-DD");
$('#ins_date').attr('value', now);
```

Comment: Date has no format() function.  Maybe your code runs in some specific browser?

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that it needs a specific library. Sorry! (delete my answer?)

Comment: @Gunnit: Updated answer to use momentjs instead of Date, which is the best date formatter I know